# Why can't Dictionary value types upcast into their super classes?

Tags: c#, types

I have a method that takes a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

```
public void myMethod(Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Why can't I pass a `Dictionary<string, string>`?  A `string` is also an object, so I feel like it should fit into that type definition. `string` should upcast to `object`.

I'm just converting the dictionary value into a string inside the method:

```
myDictionaryItem.Value.ToString();
```

So, I don't really care what it is, since everything will have a `ToString()` method. What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
public void myMethod(Dictionary<string, T> myDictionary)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Were `T` can be...whatever. This is what I was trying to get at by using `object`, but the compiler frowns on this.

Comment: It doesn't work like that for classes, the type parameters must match.

Comment: Because if you could pass `Dictionary<string, string>` there, you would be able to add any object there (`myDictionary.Add("test", 1)`), breaking type safety completely.

Comment: because you can do `dictionary.Add("Key", new object());` on a `Dictionary<string, object>` but not on a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Google covariance/contravariance and invariance.

Comment: Your code example would need to be `public void myMethod<T>(Dictionary<string, T> myDictionary)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the method's signature to use `System.Collections.IDictionary`, the interface that all dictionaries implement:

```
using System.Collections;

public static void myMethod(IDictionary myDictionary)
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in myDictionary) {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value.ToString()); // sample code
    }

}
```

Comment: That code does not compile. It still wants types for key and value. `Using the generic type 'IDictionary<TKey, TValue>' requires 2 type arguments`

Comment: @Deane: It compiles if you use a using directive of `using System.Collections;`.

Comment: That is spectacular. This is what I wanted, and I knew it existed somehow. Have an upvote, both of you.

Comment: @Deane Yeah sorry, there are two interfaces with the same name

Comment: @adjan it works, but it's quite bad IMHO (I'm not the downvoter): in your myMehtod you can add a `myDictionary.Add("AA", 3);`: it will compile, but gives you a runtime error, it's easy to break type safeti. See it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x4k3iu)

Comment: @GianPaolo It is not bad if the purpose is to view the dictionary items. The question was never about modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

It's about apples and oranges situation. Let's describe this with the animals situation:

```
IAnimalInterface<Mammal> mammals;
IAnimalInterface<Cow> cows;
// Initialize these somehow

// Imagine that this is somewhow ok.
mammals = cows;

// Since mammals are still IAnimalInterface<Mammal>
// I could even add a fish there if it was IAnimalInterface<Animal>
mammals.Add(new Dog());
```

Now imagine the concrete implementation of `IAnimalInterface<Cow>` is milking the cows. Now that's a bit embarassing for the dogs

In theory though, it makes sense to milk a dog. So if you are sure about it, you can overcome, using the `out` keyword:

```
public interface IAnimal<out T> {
    void DoBasicAction();
}
```

If you are certain that it's safe, then you can go for it. If you made a cow bark though, that wouldn't be safe.

Since the `IDictionary` interface is for really generic use, it does not allow for these kinds of variance as it can't be sure that the upcast would still remain safe for whatever actions you'd want to do.